# How to create a shortcut of a required function (`cp = FileUtils.cp`)?

Tags: ruby

I just want to call `cp` instead of `FileUtils.cp`. This is turning to be surprisingly hard to do in Ruby!

In Javascript this would simply be: `cp = FileUtils.cp`. This doesn't work in Ruby because its paren-less calling doesn't allow assigning this way (Ruby thinks I'm calling `FileUtils.cp` but I'm trying to assign it, I get the error: `wrong number of arguments (given 0, expected 1) (ArgumentError)`).

I tried `alias` but `alias cp FileUtils.cp` doesn't work because of the dot (I get the error: `syntax error, unexpected '.', expecting end-of-input`). `alias_method` would be for creating an alias within FileUtils, like `FileUtils.cp2`, but that's not what I want to do.

`cp = FileUtils.method :cp` works BUT my new shortcut is a "second-class" function, whenever I use it I have to call it as `cp.call` instead of just `cp`, thus reducing the brevity of my shortcut and forcing me to remember this new way of calling some functions.

Is there a way to simply get `cp` be `FileUtils.cp`? Thanks!

Comment: You can do `cp = FileUtils.method(:cp)`, but you would need to call it with `cp.("a", "b")` or `cp.call("a", "b")`

Comment: @maxpleaner or `cp['a', 'b']` (since @steenslag deleted his comment right after I deleted mine and we were both trying to write the same thing at the same time).

Comment: Thought bubble of programmer tasked with maintaining your code: "`cp`? What's `cp`? Let's try `method(:cp).owner #=> Object`. Hmm. There's no doc for it there...".

Comment: @CarySwoveland That's `NameError (undefined method `cp' for class `#<Class:#<Object:0x00007f98d00b6268>>')`, not `Object`. This works though: `cp.owner #=> #<Class:FileUtils>` — obviously, in scope where `cp` is defined as above. (I'd definitely still keep `FileUtils.cp` though.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a function in global space

```
def cp(src, dest, options = {})
 FileUtils.cp(src, dest, options = {})
end
```

Comment: Or add this to a module and include/extend the module wherever needed

Comment: You're right, this works. I guess I was blinded to it because I didn't want to get into the argument details of the function. I just wanted clean assignment.

Comment: ...or add to `Kernel`.

Comment: or simply `def cp(*args,&block); FileUtils.cp(*args,&block); end` no need to know the signature at all to create this.

Comment: You can also `include FileUtils` but bear in mind it will include all `FileUtils` methods. I thought it was worth mentioning this solution because it is not uncommon to use multiple methods from this module.